# Derivative of the Root of a Positive Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Suppose that the map $t \mapsto A(t)$ from some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to the set of positive matrices is differentiable. It is known that the map  $t \mapsto \sqrt{A(t)}$ is differentiable, where $\sqrt{A(t)}$ is the unique positive root of $\sqrt{A(t)}$ (and not the componentwise root of the matrix). I am looking for a proof of this fact and the expression of the derivative.

Comment: One nice method is to use the power series

Comment: Or perhaps it's possible to use the derivative of the map $t \mapsto [A(t)]^2$, which is $A(t)A'(t) + A'(t)A(t)$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the power series method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to show that the derivative exists.

As for computing it: we will have a very nice derivative **if** $A'(t)$ commutes with $A(t)$.  In particular, we find that
$$
\frac d{dt}\sqrt{A(t)} = \frac 12[A(t)]^{-1/2}A'(t)
$$
this can be confirmed via the power series for $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ centered at $x  = 1$, an applying the appropriate normalization to $A$ so that $\|A - I\|$ is within the radius of convergence.

Not sure about the more general case, though.

Comment: I guess a (1/2) factor is missing. The remark about implicit function theorem should be useful, but I am wondering if the derivative could be obtained from first principles (as can be done for the map $t \mapsto A(t)^{-1}$).